# What is element-wise max pooling?

Tags: neural-networks, extreme-value

I came across this term in the [VoxelNet paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.06396)  in relation to point cloud based object detection using machine learning. It is mentioned in figures 2&3 and in 2.2.1 
I am familiar with 2d max pooling, but this is alien to me and am struggling to find any useful information on it. After discussion with a colleague we think it may be as follows but would be grateful for a good reference/explanation: From a vector Y of vectors (y1..yk) the output z would be a vector of max values for each vector in Y:

```
Y   |   y1    |   y2    |   y3    |   y4    |   yk    |
    | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
z   | max(y1) | max(y2) | max(y3) | max(y4) | max(yk) |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the paper you reference, they do the following:

1. Assign lidar points to voxels, such that each voxel contains several points.
2. Augment the point representation by stacking the offset from the voxel centroid to the original representation (denoted $\hat p$ in the text).
3. Pass each point belonging to a voxel $\hat p_i$ through a neural net, getting some $m$-dimensional representation $f_i$ of that point.
4. Compute the maximum of each dimension over all points $f_i$ belonging to the same voxel, getting $m$-dimensional vector $\tilde f$ representing the voxel.

In terms of programming, you would have vectors $f_i$ in an array `f` of shape `(n_points_in_voxel, m)` and compute `np.max(f, axis=0)`.

Comment: I thought that this was a great response and tried the code suggestion with numpy just to check I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a particular case of 1D max pooling where the pool size and stride are the same as the length of each y_i where 1 <= i <= k.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be many implementations or definitions of this to use as reference. At least in [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1296) they define it as you are using it. Here how the issuer defined element-wise max pooling, loosely:

> Given the vector of vectors Y=y_1,...,y_k, the result would be a
>   vector z where the kth element in z would be the maximum of the kth
>   elements in Y.